# Google Sheets transpose, split, repeat, keeping blanks

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, repeat, transpose, flatten

I am in way over my head and am getting lost amongst the multiple functions. I have got messy data that I have managed to get close to where I want it, but can't fine-tune it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wXM8DowXjzCt8etP1qYo6SsA-egIlm-UOp8RnfCYv44/edit?usp=sharing
There are notes in the Sheet that explain much of what I'm trying to do.

I have used this to duplicate the Plant column, but it also duplicates the following columns (not ideal but I can live with it)

```
=ArrayFormula(vlookup(transpose(split(query(rept(row(A2:E)&" ",J2:J),,9^9)," ")), {row(A2:E),A2:J},{2,3,4,5,6},0))
```

i tried this on the Nums and Storage column:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(FLATTEN(TRIM(SPLIT(FILTER(F2:F&";*", F2:F<>""), ";", 0, 1))), "Select Col1 Where Col1 <> ''"), "*",, ))
```

but it adds spaces in the wrong place and expands to too many rows. Seems to add extra blanks.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:I1; QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(""&SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A15&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G15, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G15)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, 20)&"♦"&IF(B2:B15="", "3♦"&B2:B15, B2:B15), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G15, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G15)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, 20)&"♦"&IF(C2:C15="", "3♦"&C2:C15, C2:C15), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G15, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G15)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, 20)&"♦"&IF(D2:D15="", "3♦"&D2:D15, D2:D15), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G15, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G15)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, 20)&"♦"&IF(E2:E15="", "3♦"&E2:E15, E2:E15), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(F2:F15, ";"), "4♦"&F2:F15)&"×"&IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G15, ";"), "5♦"&G2:G15)&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G15, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G15)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, 20)&"♦"&IF(H2:H15="", "3♦"&H2:H15, H2:H15), "^1♦", ))&"×"&I2:I15), 
 "×"), ".*♦.*", ), "where Col9 is not null", 0)})
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A1:I1; QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(""&SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A9&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G9)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";")), 1))&"♦"&IF(B2:B9="", "3♦"&B2:B9, B2:B9), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G9)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";")), 1))&"♦"&IF(C2:C9="", "3♦"&C2:C9, C2:C9), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G9)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";")), 1))&"♦"&IF(D2:D9="", "3♦"&D2:D9, D2:D9), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G9)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";")), 1))&"♦"&IF(E2:E9="", "3♦"&E2:E9, E2:E9), "^1♦", ))&"×"&
 IFERROR(SPLIT(F2:F9, ";"), "4♦"&F2:F9)&"×"&IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";"), "5♦"&G2:G9)&"×"&
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";"), "2♦"&G2:G9)="",, REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(1, IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(G2:G9, ";")), 1))&"♦"&IF(H2:H9="", "3♦"&H2:H9, H2:H9), "^1♦", ))&"×"&I2:I9), 
 "×"), ".*♦.*", ), "where Col9 is not null", 0)})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @player0, i really don't know how you can look at the dataset and produce such an intricate answer - amazing. It transferred seamlessly across a few versions of this data, but i did run into one issue. There is a very unlikely but possible scenario where the "Nums" and "Storage" columns are empty: instead of exporting one row, 20 get exported - i assume related to the "Sequence(1, 20)" part. i will add a screen grab when i work out how

Comment: <https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19fPwO3rthLGiYyRewLe-rpvoG97ulJ9WB6Soy81TaTE/edit?usp=sharing>          Couldn't do a screen grab so made a copy of the sheet

Comment: @JefRo answer updated